# Get picker value inside a listview after button click

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin.Forms app in which I use a picker inside a listview.After binding the data to listview the output will have 5 pickers. I have a submit button in that page. I want to get the 5 values of picker when the button is clicked. How can I do that? Any help is appreciated.

**My Xaml**

```
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" > 
                    <ListView  x:Name="QuestionsListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                         HasUnevenRows="True"                                       
                         IsVisible="False"      
                        ItemTapped="QuestionsListView_ItemTapped"
                         CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                         SeparatorVisibility="Default"                            
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <ViewCell.View>
                                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Label Text="•" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Green" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Ques}" MaxLines="5" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#474747" Margin="0,20,0,5">                                                
                                                </Label>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0,10,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                                                <Picker x:Name="picker1" Title="Select answer" ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Text}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Gray">
                                                </Picker>                                             
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    <Button Text="Submit" BackgroundColor="#10c0d5" Clicked="evaluate_clicked" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BorderRadius="7" BorderColor="#10c0d5" BorderWidth = "2" Margin="10,5,10,10"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
```

**My Xaml.cs**

```
 private async void evaluate_clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            //How can I get the picker values?
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Picker has a property called `SelectedItem` , you can use that to get values selected in picker

Comment: @MShah Bro But can we simply referance the picker in listview ?

Comment: You can use `Data Binding` and `MVVM` for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

Add a new binding of the property **SelectedItem** .

```
 <Picker  Title="Select answer" ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Text}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Gray" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectItem ,Mode=OneWayToSource}">
  </Picker>\
```

And in your model (for example my model called Data)

```
public class Data
{
    public string Ques { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<string> Answers { get; set; }

    public string SelectItem { get; set; }

}
```

And in your **xaml.cs**

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Data data in MySource)
        {
            string selectValue = data.SelectItem;

            if(selectValue==null)
            {
                selectValue = "unSelected" ;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(selectValue);
        }

    }
```

**MySource** is the **itemSource** of your **listView**

Comment: Let me check bro

Comment: Happy coding :)